# RuntimeException in composer update

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I got error when I do composer update, it says `RuntimeException`

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Removing mews/purifier (1.0.1)



[RuntimeException]
Could not delete /var/www/myproj.com/protected/vendor/mews/purifier/LICENCE.md:



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-  lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

does anyone have an idea about my case?

Comment: Can you delete the vendor folder manually?

Comment: Check file permission on that folder..... execute ls -al @ /var/ww/html/myproj.com and paste here